Issue With Creating Bitmap From Memory Stream on Mobile (MAUI)
I have code that is supposed to take a picture and convert it to a bitmap, and it works flawlessly on Windows, both in Debug and Release mode. However, on mobile, it says that creating a bitmap with a memory stream is not supported on the platform. Perplexingly, it completely ignored my try-catch statement and just kicked the bucket. How do I get around this issue?
EDIT: System.Drawing.Common is no longer supported by non-Windows platforms, and evidently that extends to System.Drawing as well. The question is now, how do I turn an image into a bitmap with Microsoft.Maui.Graphics?
Blazor code:
<button @onclick="TakePicture">Take Picture</button>
<p>@CameraErrorMessage</p>

@code {
    string CameraErrorMessage = string.Empty;

    private async Task TakePicture()
    {
        if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
        {
            FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

            if (photo != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
                    var BitmapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(sourceStream); //line the error appears on
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CameraErrorMessage = "Getting Bitmap Failed:\n";
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry DataPair in ex.Data)
                    {
                        CameraErrorMessage += DataPair.Value??string.Empty.ToString() + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CameraErrorMessage = "Failed to take image.";
            }
        }
    }
}


I've actually already looked at that question. I tried SkiaSharp, but I couldn't get it to work. I think the solution is down a wildly different path at this point.
